# MacOS update to support smaller screen sizes

Tags: users, experience, small

Is Apple going to release a software update to make 13 inch and 14 inch Macs more readable and more optimized for user experience?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't present a user experience problem that the community can solve.

Comment: We cannot speculate on what Apple may or may not do. Is there a more generalised question that you have about designing for usability on small screens?

Comment: perhaps ask on the Apple discussion forum, or the askdifferent SE site